# Struts custom tag

Tags: java, jsp, tags, struts, custom-tag

Good evening!
*I'm using Struts 1x*
I want to write custom tag, which depends on data, stored in struts form. Now I have such code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <nested:form action="/action.do?method=index" method="post">
            <div class="className">
                <nested:text property="form.value"/>
                    some value
                <nested:submit/> 
            </div>
        </nested:form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And I want to put this code to my custom tag, but I want to keep relationship between `text input` and form field. It's clear, that output of this code, using `pageContext.getOut().write(code);` useless. I tried to google 'struts custom tags', but didn't find nothing useful. I know, that I can pass `text input` value as parameter, bit it's ugly. Could you help me? 
With best regards.